# Videoconference using Flash and SIP

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video-streaming, red5, sip

The front-end will be Flash, to run in a browser and have access to the camera.

I must use SIP to control the sessions.

How could I do this? Will a Red5 server and a MjSip sever do the trick? As in i'd use MjSip to setup the session and warn users about calls, and Red5 to stream the video and audio? Any suggestions?

Note: only 1-on-1 conference is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of red5 related options to explore, the first one is an open source project called red5phone http://code.google.com/p/red5phone/
and the other is a more commercial type offering called OpenFire that you can read about here http://community.igniterealtime.org/blogs/ignite/2008/05/05/flashbased-audio-in-openfire-part-ii